# cumulative value with several queried options

Tags: sqlite

I got a table in sqlite3 with several thousands of rows and want to create a cumulative sum for several days for specific queries. I tried some things I found here, but nothing gave me what I am searching for yet.

So here's a part of my table as example values:

```
id|killmailid|killmaildate|killmailtime|attallianceid|attcharid|attship    
69124|69295810|2018-04-12|00:57|99007379|1129992577|11393
69125|69295810|2018-04-12|00:57|99007379|90279655|29990
69126|69298874|2018-04-12|02:07|99007379|2008187055|671
69127|69300565|2018-04-12|07:32|99007379|96282716|28665
69128|69300565|2018-04-12|07:32|99007379|96734967|11198
69129|69300911|2018-04-12|10:21|99007379|90154776|608
69130|69302387|2018-04-12|11:29|99007379|91488317|23913
```

We're doing several things with the data out of this db, but now we want to get a cumulative value of attcharid's using attship.

The first thing i did is getting the DISTINCT attcharid WHERE attship = X, so my Query Looks like this:

```
SELECT killmaildate, count(DISTINCT attcharid)
FROM killdata
WHERE killmaildate BETWEEN date('2018-04-12') AND date('2018-04-30') 
AND attship = '23913' 
AND attallianceid = '99007379'
GROUP BY killmaildate;
```

Which gives me a nice list of the attcharid's using attship on each killmaildate.

```
2018-04-12|27
2018-04-14|13
2018-04-15|29
2018-04-16|10
2018-04-17|7
2018-04-18|34
2018-04-19|8
2018-04-20|39
```

Now the part which gives me some trouble. I want to add those attcharid's together, BUT it should be DISTINCT aswell, which means that only new attcharid's in attship should be added.

So, let's say 2018-04-12 has 27 attcharid's in attship, 2018-04-13 has 13 attcharid's in attship, but 10 of those were already counted on the first day, the cumulative value of 2018-04-13 should be 30 instead of 40.

I tried some things from here, which didn't really work out, my last try was something like:

```
SELECT killmaildate, sum(attcharid)
FROM ( SELECT killmaildate, count(DISTINCT attcharid) FROM killdata);
```

But ofcourse this doesn't get me where I want to be.
At the end I want to make a graph of attship in attallianceid, to see the growth of users of attship.

Comment: you forgot to add the link

Answer (score 0):

Ignore all rows that occur in some earlier group:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ...
  AND attcharid NOT IN (SELECT attcharid
                        FROM killdata AS k2
                        WHERE k2.killmaildate BETWEEN '2018-04-12' AND '2018-04-30'
                          AND k2.attship = '23913'
                          AND k2.attallianceid = '99007379'
                          AND k2.killmaildate < killdata.killmaildate)
GROUP BY ...
```